# How to expand a string in specific conditions?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to quick type `se` to `Stack Exchange`, but I also want it to stay in the built-in shortcuts (e.g. `[academia.se]`). However using

```
::se::Stack Exchange
::.se]::.se]
```

expands `[academia.se]` to `[academia.Stack Exchange]`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define your own specific ending character for one (or more) hotstrings, use the <kbd>*</kbd> sign.

I created similar hotstring (text expansion) for different languages by using a different end character.
Example:

```
:*:se\::Stack Exchange
:*:se=::Stock Exchange
:*:se]::Search Engine
```

Personally, I do this for different languages <kbd>\</kbd> for Dutch expansions, <kbd>=</kbd> for English and <kbd>]</kbd> for German. I chose the <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> ending keys because they are all close to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I even use the <kbd>.</kbd> key to create dotted abbreviations.

Example:

```
:*:ovv\::onder vermelding van
:*:ovv.::o.v.v.

:*:mw\::medewerker
:*:emp=::employee
:*:ma]::Mitarbeiter
```

I suggest that you read up on the options for Hotstrings [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**This expands `se` to `stack exchange` but does not expand anything when "[academia.se]" is typed**

```
::se::Stack Exchange
#Hotstring EndChars -()[{}:;'"/\,.?!`n `t
```

Comment: but `#Hotstring` is global, meaning that other hotstrings will be affected too. Is there a way to only apply this to this specific hotstring?